# Get date from a Django DateTimeField

Tags: python, django

I would like to request some assistance regarding this matter

I am learning django and trying out some codes but I hit a brick wall at trying to get the date only from a model's DateTimeField

here's the code that I am working on:

```
class APPLICANT_DATA(models.Model):
    SCHEDULED_AT = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)


def somefunction():
    app_data = APPLICANT_DATA.objects.all()
    for item in app_data:
        the_date = str(item.SCHEDULED_AT.strftime("%B-%d-%Y")) + ", " + the _date
```

And I am getting (`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strftime'`) even though my model contains 3 records that all have date and time

What am I doing wrong? any advice for a newbie? many thanks.

Comment: What is the meaning of  ```+ the _date```?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

### DateTimeField becomes a `datetime.datetime` object in Python

If you need a `date` object to manipulate later on, you could pull the `datetime.date` object directly from your `DateTimeField()`, using [`datetime.datetime.date()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) like below:

```
class ApplicantData(models.Model):
    scheduled_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

date = application_data.scheduled_at.date()
```

This works because Django will translate the `DateTimeField` into the Python type `datetime.datetime`, upon which we have called `date()`.

### Format the `datetime.date` like you wish

Then from that, you get a `datetime.date` object, that you can format like you wish, using [`datetime.date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

If you don't need a `date` object, you can also use `strftime` on your `datetime.datetime` object too, no problems with that. Except that your had a None field in your object.

### Dealing with `NULL`/`None` fields

If you want to allow for NULL values in `scheduled_at` you can do:

```
if application_data.scheduled_at is not None:
      date = application_data.scheduled_at.date()
```

Comment: Sorry for asking a follow-up question 5 years later @bakkal! Can you briefly explain how Django translates `DateTimeField` into Python's `datetime.datetime`? Is it by calling `to_python()`? When is it called? I asked a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65500934/django-pass-a-forms-field-to-a-models-field?noredirect=1#comment115817647_65500934

Answer (score 1):

`SCHEDULED_AT` is set to `null=True`, so sometimes `item.SCHEDULED_AT` doesn't have value so it's `None`. If you do a `.strftime` on `None` it will have the error you got. `null=True` means django model allows the field to have `NULL` value.

By the way, it's really bad practice to use all upper case for model and field names, model name should be camel case and fields should be lower case with underscore. You model name should be `ApplicantData`, field name should be `scheduled_at`.

Answer (score 0):

While in the given example the problem is most probably due to the object truly being `None`, as said in other answers, please note that you might come across such a situation in test code if you forget to clean your data by calling, e.g. `full_clean()` on your DateTimeField as in :

```
test_obj = YourModel(
    date=datetime.datetime(2016,2,26,tzfinfo=GM1),
    ...
)
test_obj.full_clean() # <-- don't forget this or you'll get a NoneType object
test_obj.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    you_field = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        date = self.created.date()
        return "%s" % str(date)
```

you can try it on the object

```
obj = YourModel.objects.filter(pk=1).get()
date = obj.created.date()
```