# convert DateTimeField to datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models

I have a `django.db.models.DateTimeField` defined here:

```
expiration = models.DateTimeField(name="expiration")
```

and I want to compare it to `datetime` like this:

```
return self.expiration > datetime.datetime.now()
```

but the pycharm gives me the following warning:

> Expected type 'datetime', got 'DateTimeField' instead
>   How can I convert `django.db.models.DateTimeField` to `datetime` to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you might find your answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300460/get-date-from-a-django-datetimefield

Comment: Something seems off here, `name` is not a valid parameter on a `DateTimeField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how to fix the problem.
in pycharm I opened

> Setting => languages & frameworks => django => enable django support

found the solution thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43867016/9355957).