# Comparing Datetime and datetimefield django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, django-database

I am Trying to compare the datetimefield stored in my item to a datetime.date object.

Here is the code in views.py where i create instances of datetime.date objects and select the datetimefield of the item from the database and try to compare them.

```
def Comapare(request,pk):
    Item = item.objects.get(id=pk)
    date1 = request.GET.get('date1')
    date2 = request.GET.get('date2')

    if date1 and date2:
        if ',' in date1:
            date1 = list(date1.split(','))
        else:
            date1 = list(date1.split(' '))
        if ',' in date2:
            date2 = list(date2.split(','))
        else:
            date2 = list(date2.split(' '))
        
        date1 = datetime.date(int(date1[0]), int(date1[1]), int(date1[2]))
        date2 = datetime.date(int(date2[0]), int(date2[1]), int(date2[2]))
        was_date1_before = date1 < date2
        if not date1 < date2:
            date1, date2 = date2, date1 

        if date1 < item.date_created:
            date1 = ''
        
        context = {
            'date1':date1,
            'date2':date2,
            'was_date1_before': was_date1_before,
            'item': Item,
        }
    else:
        context = {}

    return render(request, 'Inventory_Management/getDate.html', context)
```

when i am trying to compare them in the above example i get the following error : '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.date' and 'DeferredAttribute'
i tried to search on the internet but didn't really find anything to help.

I Get the date from the html file which is the following one

```
{% extends 'Inventory_Management/layout.html' %} {% block body %}
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date1">Date 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date1" name="date1" placeholder="Enter Date 1..">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date2">Date 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date2" name="date2" placeholder="Enter Date 2..">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
{{ date1 }} <br> {{ date2 }} <br> {{ was_date1_before }} <br> Date: {{ item.date_created|date:"M D, Y" }} {% endblock %}
```

i tried comparing the datetime.date object and the fied in my html but that didn't work.
i really need this to work, any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: which line exactly throws the error? `if date1 < item.date_created:`? If so, what format/dtype is `item.date_created`?

Comment: item.date_created is A DateTimeField and yeah that exact if statment throws the error.

Comment: so for the comparison to work, I suppose you need to cast the datetime field to a datetime.date object. did you have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35300460/get-date-from-a-django-datetimefield)?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by converting the datetime.date object into a string as follows:

```
date1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

and after replacing b=my date1 in the if statement into that, it's working!